# I'm using laravel with sqlite and I can't get the database to update from the html form

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

this is the code that's causing the error:

```
 auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);
```

this is the error:

> General error: 1 table posts has no column named updated_at

so I tested `auth()`, `user()`, `posts()` one by one and the `dd(request()->all());` works fine up until I link to the create() and it blows up.

What I've tried:

tested `public $timestamps = false;`at the Model. Also tested `const UPDATED_AT = null;` and `const CREATED_AT = null;`.

when I did that the posts table got created:

```
>>> Post::all();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3085
     all: [
       App\Post {#3080
         id: "1",
         user_id: "1",
         caption: "test",
         image: "C:\Users\php613.tmp",
       },
       App\Post {#3084
         id: "2",
         user_id: "1",
         caption: "test2",
         image: "C:\Users\phpD3FE.tmp",
       },
```

but then when I tried $user->posts it returns null:

```
>>> $user->posts;
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3062
     all: [],
   }
```

I'm new to laravel and I've been stuck on this for a whole day now. Please help.

EDIT:
here's how I'm defining the User -> Post relationship:

```
protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function profile(){
      return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }

    public function posts(){
      return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

and this is how the posts migration looks like:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('caption');
            $table->string('image');

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us how you defined the `User` model's `posts()` relationship? I think the issue is in there

Comment: Can we see your `posts table` migration?

Comment: Hi @RobBiermann I've added User - post() relationship

Comment: Hi @LobsterBaz I've provided the posts table migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the error says, your `posts` table doesn't have a column named `updated_at`.

You must add the timestamps columns (`updated_at` and `created_at`) to your migration:

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('caption');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }
```

Comment: I added that line but still getting the updated_at error

Comment: You need to re-run your migrations for the columns to be created: `php artisan migrate:fresh` (**Warning:** this will delete your database and re-run your migrations)